# Cloned rows using jQuery not submitting to post method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I need some help with javascript code im using for my django project.

for context, I'm trying to implement a button that adds new rows of inputs. The button does work (currently using jQuery to clone the previous row), but I can't get new rows to submit to the backend via the post method.

javascript code:

```
function addRow_editProduct(currentRowCount, productPK) {
 
    var rowCounter = currentRowCount + 1;
 
    var container = document.getElementById(productPK + '_productMaterialContainer');
 
    var templateRow = $('#' + productPK + '_productMaterial_row' + currentRowCount);
    var newRow = templateRow.clone();
    
    newRow.attr('id', productPK + '_productMaterial_row' + rowCounter);
    newRow.find('[id^="' + productPK + '_product_material"]').attr('id', productPK + '_product_material' + rowCounter).attr('name', productPK + '_product_material' + rowCounter);
    newRow.find('[id^="quantity"]').attr('id', 'quantity' + rowCounter).attr('name', 'quantity' + rowCounter);
    newRow.find('[id^="unit"]').attr('id', 'unit' + rowCounter).attr('name', 'unit' + rowCounter);
    newRow.find('[id^="' + productPK + '_productMaterial_pk"]').val('');
 
    newRow.find('select').val('delete'); 
    newRow.find('input[name^="quantity"]').val('');  
    newRow.find('input[name^="unit"]').val('');  
 
    newRow.find('.delete-productMaterial').attr('data-select-element-id', productPK + '_product_material' + rowCounter);
 
    $(container).append(newRow);
 
    console.log('document', $('#' + productPK + '_productMaterial_row' + rowCounter).find('[id^="' + productPK + '_product_material"]').attr('name'));
 
    
    // var formData = new FormData($('#test')[0]);
    // for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    //     console.log(pair[0] + ': ' + pair[1]);
    // }
       
}
```

html:

```
<div id="{{product_data.product.pk}}_productMaterialContainer">
    {% for y in product_data.materials %}
    <div class="row align-items-center mt-2" id="{{product_data.product.pk}}_productMaterial_row{{ forloop.counter }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="{{product_data.product.pk}}_productMaterial_pk{{ forloop.counter }}" id="{{product_data.product.pk}}_productMaterial_pk{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ y.pk }}">
        <div class="col-4">
            <select class="input-select" id="{{product_data.product.pk}}_product_material{{ forloop.counter }}" name="{{product_data.product.pk}}_product_material{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{y.material.pk}}">
                <option value="delete">None</option>
                {% for z in materials %}
                    <option value="{{z.pk}}" {% if z.pk == y.material.pk %}selected{% endif %}>{{z.name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity{{ forloop.counter }}" name="quantity{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{y.quantity}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unit{{ forloop.counter }}" name="unit{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{y.material.unit}}" readonly>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn dark-button delete-productMaterial" data-select-element-id="{{product_data.product.pk}}_product_material{{ forloop.counter }}" data-row-id="{{product_data.product.pk}}_productMaterial_row{{ forloop.counter }}"> &times </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn dark-button mt-4 addRowEditProduct" data-product-pk="{{product_data.product.pk}}">Add Row</button>
```

back-end:

```
if(request.method=="POST"):
        stock = request.POST.get("stock")
        name = request.POST.get("name")
 
        print(request.POST)
 
        
        if 'edit_form' in request.POST:
            product_pk = request.POST.get("product_pk")
            product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_pk)
            x=1
 
            while True:
                pm_pk = request.POST.get(f"{product_pk}_productMaterial_pk{x}")
                quantity = request.POST.get(f"quantity{x}")
                materialID = request.POST.get(f"{product_pk}_product_material{x}")
 
                if materialID is None:
                    break
                else:
                    if pm_pk: 
                        if materialID == "delete":
                            Product_Material.objects.filter(pk=pm_pk).delete()
                        else:
                            Product_Material.objects.filter(pk=pm_pk).update(material=materialID, quantity=quantity)
                    else:
                        if materialID != "delete":
                            material_object = get_object_or_404(Material, pk=materialID)
                            Product_Material.objects.create(product=product, material=material_object, quantity=quantity)
                x+=1
            Product.objects.filter(pk=product_pk).update(stock=stock, name=name)
            return redirect('products')
```

(i just included the back-end for extra context, it isn't complete since I've just been trying to figure out why cloned rows aren't submitting)

I know that the new row ids are being updated correctly via console logs:

```
document 39_product_material3
products:1128 document 39_product_material4
products:1128 document 39_product_material5
```

and i can see the rows being added correctly.

However, the cloned row inputs are nowhere to be found when i print the request.POST in my backend

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['2KJ70EwX6mog6lTkfQH7d9ykkBcBLXbFIbKFfRBwJzGMDGEfKQSas9R5WJ2KbyPQ'], 'edit_form': ['1'], 'product_pk': ['39'], 'name': ['123'], '39_productMaterial_pk1': ['49'], '39_product_material1': ['49'], 'quantity1': ['1'], 'unit1': ['per inch'], '39_productMaterial_pk2': ['51'], '39_product_material2': ['50'], 'quantity2': ['2'], 'unit2': ['per inch'], 'stock': ['112'], 'cost': ['']}>
```

I have no clue as to why nothing from the cloned rows are being submitted via post.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. I'm also open to completely revamping the code if it can fufill the same function

Comment: Welcome to SO. just write minimum code .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lean more into JQuery and use Ajax instead of html forms, this is how I would do it..
with the added benefit of moving away from using `id="{{id}}_something_{{loopcounter}}"` (**been there!**) and instead grabbing items based on their relative location in the DOM with `.parent()` (up) / `.find()` (down)

---

### HTML

1. added `{% csrf_token %}`, important to include in javacsript/ajax post
2. Moved all `id="{{id}}__blah__{{count}}"` to `class="blah"`
3. `.productMaterialContainer` now has an attribute `pk`
4. `.productMaterial_row` now has an attribute `pk`
5. added button `.submit_btn` for submitting form (remove any wrapped `<form>`
   elements)

```html
<!-- token must be on page for ajax -->
{% csrf_token %}

<div pk="{{product_data.product.pk}}"
     class="productMaterialContainer">

    {% for y in product_data.materials %}
    <div pk="{{ y.pk }}"
         class="productMaterial_row row align-items-center mt-2">

        <div class="col-4">
            <select class="product_material input-select" value="{{y.material.pk}}">
                <option value="delete">None</option>
                {% for z in materials %}
                    <option value="{{z.pk}}" {% if z.pk == y.material.pk %}selected{% endif %}>{{z.name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <input type="number" class="quantity form-control" value="{{y.quantity}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <input type="text" class="unit form-control" value="{{y.material.unit}}" readonly>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-1">
            <button type="button" class="delete-productMaterial btn dark-button "> &times </button>
        </div>

    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn dark-button mt-4 addRowEditProduct" data-product-pk="{{product_data.product.pk}}">Add Row</button>

<!-- Submit Button to Call Ajax POST -->
<button type="button" class="btn submit_btn" data-product-pk="{{product_data.product.pk}}">Submit Data</button>
```

**Note:** I wasn't sure how `delete-productMaterial` worked, so I didn't add anything. You could do something like this: `$(this).closest('.productMaterial_row').find('.product_material').val('delete')` on click. **Edit:** Missed class dots in closest + find

### JQuery

1. `addRowEditProduct` event moved to a `$(".addRowEditProduct").click()` with a
   simpler clone-to-edit flow
2. Ajax Submit attached to `submit_btn`, packs material data into an
   array-of-dicts which is encoded in JSON.
3. Ajax request handles redirect and displays any error msgs from view.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".delete-productMaterial").click(function(){
        parent_pk = $(this).attr("data-product-pk");
        parent = $(".productMaterialContainer[pk='"+parent_pk+"']");

        // fetch a row from target product and clone it
        cloned_row = parent.find(".productMaterial_row").first().clone();

        // remove pk + flag as new
        cloned_row
            .attr("pk", "")
            .addClass("new_item");

        // reset fields
        cloned_row.find(".product_material").val("");
        cloned_row.find(".quantity").val("");
        cloned_row.find(".unit")
            .val("")
            .removeAttr("readonly");

        // add to form
        parent.append(cloned_row);
    });

    $(".submit_btn").click(function(){
        parent_pk = $(this).attr("data-product-pk");
        // fetch the container that is attached to submit button
        parent = $(".productMaterialContainer[pk='"+parent_pk+"']");

        // pack rows
        material_data = [];
        error = false;
        $.each($(parent).find(".productMaterial_row"), function(counter, row){
            // fetch all values in relation to current material row
            // Note: `.find()` looks 'down' or for children

            tmp = {
                "pk": $(row).attr("pk"),
                "material_id": $(row).find(".product_material").val(),
                "unit": $(row).find(".unit").val(),
            }

            // might be a good idea to add validation too..
            if ($(row).find(".quantity").val() == ""){
                $(row).find(".quantity").addClass("red-border");
                error = true;
            }else{
                $(row).find(".quantity").removeClass("red-border");
                tmp["quantity"] = $(row).find(".quantity").val();
            }

            if (!error){
                // add to array if there's no errors
                material_data.push(tmp);
            }
        });

        if (error){
            alert("Please fix red-borders");
            return;
        }

        // pack form data
        submit_data = {
            "product_pk": parent,
            "stock" = $("some_stock_field_by_parent_id").val(),
            "name" = $("some_stock_field_by_parent_id").val(),
            "material_data" = JSON.stringify(material_data), // encode
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken": $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(), // pack token (REQUIRED!)
        }

        $.ajax({
            method: "post",
            data: submit_data,
            success: function(data){
                if (data["status"]){
                    // redirect to returned url
                    window.location = data["url"];
                }else{
                    // controlled error, display message
                    alert(data["msg"]);
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                // Basic `xhr.status` Key
                // 0    = Server didn't Reply (Server Down)
                // 400  = Bad Request         (Syntax Error)
                // 403  = Forbidden           (Login Token Expired)
                // 403  = Not Found           (Invalid Url)
                // 500  = Server Error        (Django Crash)
                alert("something broke")  // uncontrolled error
            }
        });
    });

});
```

### View

1. removed `get_object_or_404`, for manually checking + returning msg to ajax on fail. (Ajax doesn't do redirects, that I know of)
2. Decode `material_data` with `json.loads()`
3. Validate all objects exist in material_data before committing to editing/saving anything
4. at the end return dictionary to Ajax using JsonResponse instead of using a redirect call

**Note:** No unit in update or new?

```py
def my_view(request):
    if(request.method=="POST"):
        stock = request.POST.get("stock")
        name = request.POST.get("name")

        print(request.POST)

        if request.POST.get("product_pk"):
            # product_pk exists => is edit form

            # dict to be returned to Ajax.
            #   status = False -> bad. Always assume bad.
            data = {"status": False}
            # for any error. True -> STOP + Return to Ajax.
            error = False

            # Note: `get_object_or_404` doesn't work with Ajax, instead
            #   use .filter().first() -> returns obj or None
            product = Product.objects.filter(pk=request.POST.get("product_pk")).first()
            if not product:
                error = True
                data["msg"] = f"Product in db row {request.POST.get('product_pk')} not found"


            if not error:
                # decode material data
                #   try not really needed, but why not.
                try:
                    import json
                    material_data = json.loads(request.POST.get('material_data'))
                except ValueError:
                    error = True
                    data["msg"] = "Failed tp parse Material Data"

            if not error:
                # The problem: get_object_or_404(Material) **in** the loop is a
                # no go.. we don't want to edit+save 4 and then crash at the
                # 5th. 
                # Solution: Pre-Validate that the items exist
                for count, d in enumerate(material_data):
                    if error:
                        break

                    if d["pk"]:
                        tmp = Product_Material.objects.filter(pk=d['pk']).first()
                        if tmp:
                            d["product_material_obj"] = tmp  # save for later
                        else:
                            error = True
                            data['msg'] = f"Product_Material in db row {d['pk']} on form row {count} was not found"

                    if d["material_id"] != "delete":
                        # Hit for Edit + New
                        tmp = Material.objects.filter(pk=d['material_id']).first()
                        if tmp:
                            d["material_obj"] = tmp  # save for later
                        else:
                            error = True
                            data['msg'] = f"Material in db row {d['material_id']} on form row {count} was not found"

            if not error:
                # all validation passed, actually do change
                for d in material_data:
                    if d["pk"]:
                        if d["material_id"] == "delete":
                            d["product_material_obj"].delete()
                        else:
                            d["product_material_obj"].quantity = d["quantity"]
                            d["product_material_obj"].material = d["material_obj"]
                            d["product_material_obj"].save()
                    else:
                        if d["material_id"] != "delete":
                            Product_Material.objects.create(
                                product=product,
                                material=d["material_obj"],
                                quantity=d['quantity'],
                            )

                Product.objects.filter(pk=product_pk).update(stock=stock, name=name)

            if not error:
                # all went good
                data['status'] = True
                data['msg'] = "Form submitted."
                data['url'] = reverse('products')  # URL to direct is str

            # return dict to ajax
            from django.http import JsonResponse
            return JsonResponse(data)
```

---

This is generally spit balling, so there might be a thing or two wrong, let me
know if you decide to do it this way and run into problems.

---

**Edit:** Fixed invalid Jquery with `parent`

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I appreciate it.
I'll definitely look into this, learn from it, and try implementing it instead.